# Simple sequence of experiments

Tags: probability

If I have an experiment with $\frac{1}{2}$ probability of success, how many times I have to run as to be 99.9% sure I am successful? Is someone please able to explain how to resolve this step-wise?

As I saw this problem in a video, I already know that the result for this question is 10 - however I don't know how to get to that number.

Thanks.

Comment: We want the probability of $n$ failures in a row to be less than $0.001$. If we assume independence, the probability of $n$ failures in a row is $(1/2)^n$.

Comment: Thanks for this. I saw this problem in a video and the result was magically "10". I just would like to know please how to get to that number.

Comment: $2^{10}=1024$, so $(1/2)^{10}$ is a bit less than $0.001$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability you are not successful in $n$ trials is $\left(\frac 12\right)^n$, so the probability you are successful **at least once** in $n$ trials is $1-\left(\frac 12\right)^n$. To we need to solve the inequality $$1-\left(\frac 12\right)^n>0.999$$
$$\Rightarrow\left(\frac 12\right)^n<0.001$$
$$\Rightarrow n\log(0.5)<\log(0.001)$$
But $\log(0.5)<0$ so we reverse the inequality, and$$n>\frac{\log(0.001)}{\log(0.5)}$$

Comment: Thanks for this. I saw this problem in a video and the result was magically "10". I just would like to know please how to get to that number from your above result.

Comment: calculate the last expression, and you want the next integer so 10 is the answer!

Comment: Yes, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log%280.001%29%2Flog%280.5%29

Answer (score 0):

You can first time be successful at the first trial. The probility is $0.5$

You can first time be successful at the second trial. The probility is $0.5^2$

You can first time be successful at the third trial. The probility is $0.5^3$

You can first time be successful at the nth trial. The probility is $0.5^n$

Summing up these probabilities $\sum_{i=1}^n 0.5^i\geq 0.999$

$\sum_{i=1}^n 0.5^i$ can be simplified by the formula for the partial sum of a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

$\sum_{i=1}^n 0.5^i=1-\frac{1}{2^n}\geq 0.999$

$0.001\geq\frac{1}{2^n}$

$2^n\geq \frac{1}{0.001}$

$2^n\geq 1000$

I´m sure you can take it from here.